# Laravel task scheduling commands not working

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I'm running laravel 5.1 and I'm having some issues with the laravel Task Scheduling. The problem is that some of the commands are running, but others aren't. I have no explanation at all for this...

I've got 2 commands as defined like this:

```
$schedule->command('some:command')
    ->cron('00 00 * * *');

$schedule->command('some:other:command')
    ->cron('50 00 * * 7');
```

Both of my commands are listed in the protected `$commands` array.

The `some:command` command runs fine every day but the `some:other:command` isn't running at all. When I call the command itself with `php artisan` everything works fine. It's the same issue when I change the `->cron()` function to the `->dailyAt('00:00');` function.

This problem only occurs on my staging environment, on production everything runs fine. Both environments are 100% the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bit late to the party but hopefully it can help other users:

The problem was that the cron jobs had logging enabled.
For some reason the stream to those files was never closed and new runs caused a Permission denied error. This error wasn't logged because logging didn't work...

This also explains why it worked on other environments.

Answer (score 1):

The last digit of a cron schedule should be a value of `0 - 6`. 7 is not supported by most crons.
If you want to run your cron every sunday, it is best to use `0`.

Like so:

```
$schedule->command('some:other:command')
    ->cron('50 00 * * 0');
```

Comment: Possibly another date/time setting on your production server.

Comment: I changed the value to 0 but the problem is still not fixed. Worked on production, but not on staging